# Kotlin ViewPager Null PointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm trying to get a `viewpager` in an already existing **fragment**.
In another project I had no issues when the `viewpager` was in activity_main.xml

One of the things I tried is the following:

**ViewPagerAdapter.kt**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> KapperKeuze1Fragment()
            1 -> KapperKeuze2Fragment()
            else -> KapperKeuze3Fragment()
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 3
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var homeFragment: HomeFragment
lateinit var afspraakFragment: AfspraakFragment
lateinit var overFragment: OverFragment

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val bottomNavigation : BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bot_nav)

    homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_layout, homeFragment)
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
        .commit()

    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> {
                homeFragment = HomeFragment()
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_layout, homeFragment)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit()
            }
            R.id.afspraak -> {
                afspraakFragment = AfspraakFragment()
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_layout, afspraakFragment)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit()
            }
            R.id.over -> {
                overFragment = OverFragment()
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_layout, overFragment)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit()
            }
        }
        true
    }
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    val pager = findViewById<View>(R.id.viewPager) as ViewPager
    pager.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

**fragment_afspraak.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The error occurs in **MainActivity.kt** at: `val pager = findViewById<View>(R.id.viewPager) as ViewPager`

And gives:

> Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

Comment: `R.id.viewPager` is not in your `R.layout.activity_main` which you have not posted

Comment: @tyczj i want the viewpager to be inside an already existing fragment, when i put the viewpager in main that doesn't happen. So how can i get it inside another layout?

Comment: why don't you implement your viewPager in your fragment???!!
you can simply implement your ViewPager in your fragment in **onCreateView** or **onViewCreated** methods of your fragment

Comment: @AlirezaBideli That's what I want, but ive been googling for multiple hours now on how to do that, im new to kotlin and android development. How would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Use **childFragmentManager** instead of **supportFragmentManager**

Because it returns a private **FragmentManager** for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.(You ViewPager fragments located in you afspraak fragment)

So set your **ViewPager**  in your **AfspraakFragment** as below :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
    val pager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager) as ViewPager
    pager.adapter = adapter
}
```